# Is there recognition of Frakes' acting?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes

I predict downvote, but please bear with me -- this ***is*** an objective question.

Preamble:
People often criticize the acting on Star Trek, including TNG.  Rewatching TNG from the beginning, there are (IMO) a few cast members obviously in the 'bad acting' camp and a few in the 'good acting camp'.

I recognize this is subjective, but for me,
Bad acting (as in not convincing): Gates McFadden, Diana Muldaur, Levar Burton, Wil Wheaton, Marina Sirtis
Good acting: Patrick Stewart, Brent Spiner, Michael Dorn and ***Jonathan Frakes***

This may be controversial, but if you look at how Frakes delivers each line differently, with appropriate contextual tone and expression, but not too much, it seems clear he put a lot of thought into every performance.

Question: is there any general acknowledgment (awards, reviews, commentary, etc.) of Jonathan Frakes demonstrating good acting skill on Star Trek?   (Or is it just me?)

Comment: Self comments:   it seems I've put the women in the 'bad' camp.  Well, chalk it up to bad casting or bad writing.   Sorry.

Comment: Additional commentary:  This really doesn't go here, but I need to make the comment.   While TNG was airing, my brother did a market research interview for a few bucks.   Apparently someone was considering using Frakes for a shampoo commercial and wanted to research whether this would be well-received.   Apparently they never signed him up.

Comment: “I’m not really a starship officer, I just play one on TV. But whether I’m in front of the cameras or facing down a Klingon armada, there’s one thing I rely on — the vibrant body and lustrous shine afforded by Neutrogena T-Gel dandruff shampoo. Make it so!” He’s certainly the best thing in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVHm02FeCH8).

Comment: I wouldn't downvote, but I would probably argue this question belongs on Movies & TV SE, and not on this SE, since it's not about the scifi/fantasy world the show encompasses or the series itself but rather a generic acting question.

Comment: @BBlake:  I do believe it is considered on topic, but acknowledged -- just like any question about casting or production of an SF show is on topic even if the question itself doesn't relate to a scifi element.

Comment: @BBlake Per the [help center](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions about behind-the-scenes information is on-topic

Comment: Sirtis is actually a great actor (cf. *Mass Effect*, *Gargoyles*), the writers just didn't know what to do with her (they had the same problem with Kate Mulgrew on VOY).  You try delivering "I'm sorry, I have a headache, no it's not anything to worry about, I'll just go lie down" with a straight face for the 47th time.

Comment: This isn't really "behind the scenes" IMO, but it's a minor quibble. It's not really about Star Trek TNG per se, but about Frakes' acting achievements. But as I say, a minor quibble.

Comment: I have nothing against this question.  It relates to a sci-fi franchise and is answerable, and brings up an interesting point about the unevenness of the acting on *TNG*. +1

Comment: Frakes was dreadful, until he grew the beard.  +1

Comment: I vividly remember his Performance in "Frame of mind".

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   Close.  I actually do believe it may have been Head and Shoulders -- is there something about him that makes it look like he has dandruff issues?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : Here's a better [version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzUX_1jaO_I).

Comment: @JonathanFrakes:   Where are you to accept my compliment?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Not sure if you knew this, but very early in Frakes' acting career, he was paid by Marvel to appear as Captain America at conventions. [This](http://www.plaidstallions.com/marvel/captainamericaad.jpg) is apparently him.

Comment: We all seem to have forgotten his electric turn in [*Shades of Gray*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_Gray_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   What no [*Fifty Shades of Grey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty_Shades_of_Grey) crossover spoof?

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I once made a girl watch *Shades of Gray* fifty times, which is much worse than anything in that tawdry book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Frakes was honoured with a **Life Career Award at the 39th Saturn Awards in 2013**.

[image]

From the Press Release:

> The Academy of Science Fiction, Fantasy & Horror Films is happy to announce that actor and director JONATHAN FRAKES, whose impressive body of work includes **playing Commander William T. Riker in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*** and its big-screen movies as well as directing such series as *Castle*, *NCIS: Los Angeles*, *Leverage*, *Roswell*, and *V*, will receive this year’s Life Career Award.
>
> He joins this year’s previously announced special-award recipients Richard Matheson, William Friedkin, and Vince Gilligan and will receive his award in person during the award ceremonies.

He was given the award **at least partly for his efforts during *TNG*'s television run.**

About the Saturn Awards:

> The Saturn Awards is the official award presentation voted by the members of the **The Academy of Science Fiction, Fantasy, and Horror Films**.
>
> The Saturn Awards is an **acknowledgement of fine work**. Some of it is ground-breaking, some of it is vastly entertaining, but the bottom line should be that **the recognition is well earned.**

Frakes is the only *TNG*  actor to have received a Saturn Award, let alone a Life Career Award.  (Patrick Stewart was nominated three times for a Saturn Award, but never won one.)

This particular recognition puts Frakes amongst the likes of individuals such as Ray Bradbury and Gene Roddenberry, and actors Rock Hudson, Ann Robinson, Vincent Price, Lance Henriksen, and Malcolm McDowell — each received a Saturn Award.

([Source](http://www.saturnawards.org/))

Regarding praise for specific instances of Frakes' portrayal of Riker on television, the [official Star Trek site](http://www.startrek.com/) very recently posted a retrospective on the Riker-centric episode ["Frame of Mind"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Frame_of_Mind_%28episode%29):

- ["Frame of Mind"...22 years later](http://www.startrek.com/article/frame-of-mind-22-years-later)

The article is quick to point out:

> The season-six hour remains a **fan favorite**, in large part thanks to the **powerful performance by Jonathan Frakes**, who plays Riker as a man losing his mind in the complex, layered, even trippy dramatic episode.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 13):

I'm focusing on the awards aspect, since that one is more objectively answerable.

According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000408/awards), Frakes has only been nominated for one award based on his acting in *Star Trek*: a [Blockbuster Entertainment Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockbuster_Entertainment_Awards) in the "Favorite Supporting Actor - Science Fiction" category, for his role in *Star Trek: First Contact*<sup>1</sup>.

Compared to the rest of the TNG ensemble, Frakes is pretty middle-of-the-road in this regard:

- Patrick Stewart has [7 nominations and 1 win](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001772/awards?ref_=nm_awd)
- Brent Spiner has [3 nominations and 1 win](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000653/awards?ref_=nm_awd)
- Wil Wheaton has [2 nominations and 1 win](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000696/awards?ref_=nm_awd)
- Michael Dorn has [1 nomination](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000373/awards?ref_=nm_awd) (but it's for DS9)

Marina Sirtis, Gates McFadden, and LeVar Burton all have no *Star Trek* awards.

---

<sup>1</sup> [He lost to Brad Pitt for his role in *Twelve Monkeys*](http://www.imdb.com/event/ev0000104/1997). Interestingly Patrick Stewart was nominated for "Favorite Actor - Science Fiction", but he lost to Will Smith (*Independence Day*)

Comment: OK, but these are based on the films, where he didn't have big roles.   Info related to the TV series would be more apt.

Comment: @ThePopMachine No, this is everything. So far as I can find, Frakes has zero other awards (nominations or otherwise) for *Star Trek* work outside of *First Contact*

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Jason is correct. IMDB lists all awards and nominations, TV or Film.